# nginx:which port send the request?

Tags: nginx

I am using nginx as forward proxy. I want to record all the ports nginx is using. Now I know `$server_port` is the listened port. Nginx receives request from listened port, then creates a new connection and sends the request to `$upstream_addr`. How can I log the new connection's port to access.log?

Comment: Are you trying to log the upstream port? See `$upstream_addr` in [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_upstream_module.html#variables).

Comment: No. `$upstream_addr` is server's ip and port, I want to log client's port.